# Android: Fusion drawable to create a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm developing an App where the user can add Different logo (drawable) on a T-shirt (drawable too..).

What I was wondering, as there is no "snapshot" method with android unless being rooted (or to use the snapshot lib that uses a 3rd party service and I don't want that)
Is there  way to fusion my drawable to create a .PNG ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help
http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx

You should do some research with those key words
android canvas to bitmap

cheers

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy solution:

http://code.neenbedankt.com/how-to-render-an-android-view-to-a-bitmap